# Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::getConnectionName does not exist

Tags: laravel

where comes from this bugg  ?  after having done a php artisan route:list showing that a 'navbar.index' route exists, I try to use it in a <a href= '{{route('navbar.index'}}> but I have the following error

Comment: Share with us what's error you are getting?

Comment: What you mean ?  the error is "Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::getConnectionName does not exist"

Comment: while i enter inside of <a href= '{{route('navbar.index'}}>

Comment: Using `route()` helper to create a URL and having a connection's name through Eloquent is irrelevant. You need to share more detail.

Comment: Would you please share the controller code that redirects to this view? this error usually appears because of model relation error

Comment: @RatebHabbab You're right i found the solution in the Models relation